# How to register a device token to Sendbird server?

Tags: ios, swift, sendbird

In the [Sendbird docs](https://sendbird.com/docs/chat/v3/ios/guides/push-notifications?_ga=2.208704598.531859910.1685345246-1874627654.1676991650#2-step-4-register-a-device-token-to-sendbird-server) on how to add Push notifications there is this line:

```
if status == SBDPushTokenRegistrationStatus.pending
```

But I get an error: Cannot find 'SBDPushTokenRegistrationStatus' in scope
If I try to add pod 'SendBirdSDK' along with pod 'SendBirdUIKit' and pod 'SendBirdDesk' - I am getting a lot of errors in the Xcode like:
'SBDPushTokenRegistrationStatus' has been renamed to 'PushTokenRegistrationStatus'
'SBDFileMessage' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'SendBirdSDK.SBDFileMessage' found property
etc

How can I add Sendbird Push notifications to the project?